# Pandas : Apply function on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a new column calculated from first quartile of all columns.
something like this:

```
df['Q25']=df[col].apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25) ,axis =1)
#col = ['1', '2','3',..'29'] days in one month
```

and this is the error I receive:

```
KeyError: "['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11' '12' '13' '14' '15' '16'\n '17' '18' '19' '20' '21' '22' '23' '24' '25' '26' '27' '28' '29'] not in index"
```

I understand that error shows python is trying to find passed list (col) in the index, instead of columns itself but I don't know how should I fix it. I already added axis=1 but with no luck.

PS. I can't add column manually like `df['1'], df['2']` since the total number (in this case 29) changes in other cases.

Comment: What is `df.columns`?

Comment: @NickilMaveli `Int64Index([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
            18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
           dtype='int64', name='Day')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
df['Q25']= [np.percentile(df.loc[i,:], 25) for i in df.index]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work:  **TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'**

Comment: Another point: your code uses index ( rows) while I want to consider columns. I changed your code to this : `df['Q25']= [np.percentile(df[:,i], 25) for i in map(lambda l : str(l), df.columns)]` and received the same error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' `

Comment: You cannot add a column to your `df` of size the size of `df.columns`. It does not mean anything. The shapes are not the same. You might want to add a new row ...

Comment: Thanks again , but also the new code (without changing it for columns) results in the same error

Comment: My bad, I tried it again and it's working. The bad news (for me!) is that for the rows containing NaN, the Q25 value is NaN but it's a different issue and I'll try to search it. Thanks a lot for your help - And sorry that I can't vote up your answer, my reputation is so low for that!

Comment: You can use the **pandas.Dataframe.fillna()** method to fill *NaN* values. It will be a little bit tricky to keep your quartile unchanged after imputing the values but I think its feasible ;)